# VBA: Printer list

Tags: vba, loops, printing, date-difference

I want to develop a print system for check a daily list of documents to print and do it every hour.

Until now I could print one document but when the time has come to print more the code only works for the first.

```
Sub printTag()

Dim strCommand As String
Dim filePath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim printer As String
Dim numRefs As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim ref As String
Dim numFiles As Integer
Dim t As Integer
Dim difD As Long
Dim difH As Long
Dim difM As Long
Dim listDate As Date
Dim nowDate As Date

nowDate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Print").Range("B8")
printer = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Print").Range("B2")
numRefs = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List").Columns("A"))
numFiles = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Relation").Columns("A"))

For x = 1 To numRefs
    On Error Resume Next
    listDate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List").Range("A" & x)
    difD = DateDiff("d", nowDate, listDate)
    If difD = 0 Then
    difH = DateDiff("h", nowDate, listDate)
    difM = DateDiff("n", nowDate, listDate)
        If difH = 0 Then
            If difM >= 0 Then
                For t = 1 To numFiles
                    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List").Range("B" & x) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Relation").Range("A" & t) Then
                        filePath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Print").Range("B1") & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Relation").Range("B" & t)
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Print").Range("B3") = strCommand
                        strCommand = "PRINT " & filePath & "/D:" & printer
                        Shell strCommand, 1
                    End If
                Next t
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd got the idea to create a script instead send multiples instances in command line and works perfectly. This is the result:

```
Sub printTag()

Dim strCommand As String
Dim filePath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim printer As String
Dim numRefs As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim ref As String
Dim numFiles As Integer
Dim t As Integer
Dim difD As Long
Dim difH As Long
Dim difM As Long
Dim listDate As Date
Dim nowDate As Date

nowDate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Print").Range("B8")
printer = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Print").Range("B2")
numRefs = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List").Columns("A"))
numFiles = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Relation").Columns("A"))

If Len(Dir$(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\list.bat")) > 0 Then
     Kill ThisWorkbook.Path & "\list.bat"
End If
intFile = FreeFile()
Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\list.bat" For Output As #intFile

For x = 1 To numRefs
    On Error Resume Next
    listDate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List").Range("A" & x)
    difD = DateDiff("d", nowDate, listDate)
    If difD = 0 Then
    difH = DateDiff("h", nowDate, listDate)
    difM = DateDiff("n", nowDate, listDate)
        If difH = 0 Then
            If difM >= 0 Then
                For t = 1 To numFiles
                    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List").Range("B" & x) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Relation").Range("A" & t) Then
                        filePath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Print").Range("B1") & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Relation").Range("B" & t)
                        Print #intFile, "PRINT " & filePath & " /D:" & printer
                    End If
                Next t
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next x
Print #intFile, "exit"
Close #intFile

End Sub
```